# How can I get settings in .profile to work in GUI desktop?

Tags: environment-variables, desktop-environment

My emacs configuration uses an environment variable set in `.profile`, and I realized that it is not available when I run emacs from the desktop shortcut.

It is available when  emacs GUI is run from the terminal though.

Somehow the X login, ie KDE5 is not executing `.profile`. How can it be configured to run the settings in `.profile`?

```
umask 002
export HOST=$(hostname)
```

Comment: Most systems do load `.profile` during the login process, so `.profile` is the right place to set an environment. But there are a few systems where `.profile` is not loaded by default. What distribution are you running, and what display manager (the program where you type your login and password)?

Answer (score -1):

That's because `.profile` is for text shell. Since you are using GUI as login shell, variables which are set in `.profile` are accessible when you start text shell.

KDE as any other desktop environment has it's own config files. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167955/taking-kde-config-files-with-me) thread, config files for KDE are stored in `~/.kde/share/config` and `~/.kde/share/apps`

Comment: Most systems do read `.profile` at login time. If by “when you start text shell” you meant “when you open a terminal” then your second sentence is false: `.profile` is not read when you open a terminal, unless you run a login shell which is not the default configuration except on macOS and not a good design. The KDE configuration files you listed are not relevant.